# Jsoup - arrangement of table data from website

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get the table from https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia.
Here is the table I want from the website.

[image: Table]

But the result is not what I want.

[image: myResult]

I have got **2 questions**:

**1st Question** is how can I arrange them like a table with arrangement **Row** and **Column** similar with the table from my picture. Below is my source code on how i get the data.

```
String URL = "https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements trs = doc.select("#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(148)");
String currentRow = null;
for (Element tr : trs){
    Elements tdDay = tr.select("tr:has(th)");
        currentRow = tdDay.text();
        System.out.print(currentRow);
}
```

**2nd Question** is from my source code, is it the best way to scraping the particular data from all the element like for example the element from the website https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia by using

```
Elements trs = doc.select("#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(148)");
```

Because from the website, there have got **3** table class with name wikitable. `<table class="wikitable">`. So how can I call only particular table?

Comment: @luksch the image is the result not my code.

Answer (score 0):

Since the website u provide has some `wikitable` in it. So u can try to find out the selector of the data from table and I found there is `<td>` and `<th>`.

```
for (int i = x; i < x; i++) {
    Elements trs = doc.select("#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(148) > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > th");
    Elements tds = doc.select("#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(148) > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + i + ") > td");
```

try this while the `x` in the `for` loops is the number of row in the table so it can scrape the data

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String URL = "https://ms.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
    //Select the table which is under the header containing "Trivia" 
    //having the value "wikitable" for the class attribute
    Element table = doc.select("h2:contains(Trivia)+[class=\"wikitable\"]").first();
    //then select each row of the table 
    Elements trs = table.select("tr");
    //for each row get first and second child corresponding to column 1 and two of table
    for (Element tr : trs){
        Element th = tr.child(0);
        Element td = tr.child(1);
        System.out.printf("%-40s %-40s%n",th.text(), td.text());
    }
}
```